# Set Community Redirect Page after Reset Password

Tags: community

I have set up a Customer Community with Self-Registration. I am having users register without setting a password. They receive the "Welcome Email" after self-registration.

The email has a link for the user to set their password.

After they set their password, the user is redirected to a Visualforce Page- how do I set this to an `Experience Builder Page`? I am not using Visualforce pages for my community.

The page that is being displayed is set in `Administration -> Sites & Domains -> Custom URLs`, then click the field under "Site Label" with `Site Type = "Community"` (*Note* clicking this when `Type = Site.com Community` returns a bad URL...

Now "Active Site Homepage" is a Visualforce Page, and that is all that's selectable (Not sure how this influences **Experience Builder Page**, however, *removing access to certain Visualforce Pages* under the related list: `Site Visualforce Pages` *removes access to Experience Builder Pages* for **no documented reason**?

For reference:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hack'ish fix:

There is an undocumented relationship between `Site`, `Communities`, `Experience Builder` & `Visualforce Page` & `Site.com Studio`.

The page that `{!Community_Url}` redirects to in email merge templates following password resets is set by `Administration->Site->Active Site Home Page` (prefixed with your Community Domain Url):

`/apex/CommunityHomepage` (this is a required field).

Modify this Visualforce Page like so:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" 
sidebar="false" 
action="{!redirect}" 
controller="CommunityHomepageController">

</apex:page>
```

```
public Pagereference redirect(){
  Network myNetwork = [SELECT Id FROM Network WHERE Name ='Community Name' ];
  ConnectApi.Community  myCommunity = ConnectApi.Communities.getCommunity(myNetwork.id);
  Pagereference pr = new Pagereference(myCommunity.siteUrl);
  pr.setRedirect(true);
  return pr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very easy declarative admin settings change. Go to your community Administration page and to the Login section (Workspaces --> Administration --> Login). There you will be able to select a Home Page. From the dropdown select the Builder page option, and then in the lookup select the one you want.

[image]

Update 2:40pm PST

The easiest way to solve this is to keep the Site.com config as "main" (which is what you select in the loop in the administration setup) and create a new Home Page variation and make that the active one in the Community Builder. This might require some export/import actions to take OR manually create it in the builder. If you already have a pre-configured lightning page, it is a matter of using that one as a Home Page variation.

Comment: when I select `Experience Builder Page` I do not have the option to select any of my `Experience Builder Pages` I have two options `main` and `login` I do not have any pages labeled `main` in the "Experience Builder", the setting was already "Experience Builder Page" when I attempted to change it?

Comment: "Note When Experience Builder is selected, only published Site.com Studio pages are included in the search results". You would have to go to the Site.com studio to publish the page you want to use seems like.

Comment: To go to Site.com -when you are in the Community Lightning Builder, remove all the parameters from the URL and it will take you there

Comment: Added a screenshot of `Site.com Studio` (`Administration`->`Site.com Studio`), I've deleted `login` set "Community Homepage" to the default page, I cannot delete `main` as it says it is my community's active home? It says I have to set a new homepage under Site Configuration? But I don't know where this menu is? I've added some screen-shots above for reference- How do I select community builder pages to publish in `Site.com Studio`?

Comment: I'm not sure you would have to delete the login page. In this case you need a new site landing page setup as your default home page. BUT from what I was thinking, it would be easier to just create another Home page variation in the lightning builder and assign that one as the active one. You will need to import your page but it will link to the main landing site, saving you from making changes in Site.com - sorry for changing directions now- It just makes sense from a maintainability perspective and it makes sure a LINK exists between your Site.com landing page and your community builder page.

Comment: I'm not sure how Site.com "main" is linked to Home Page - if we were able to create that sort of linkage between community builder and Site.com that would be the perfect solution (being able to reuse an existing community builder page and setting the Site.com landing page)

Comment: Sorry not sure I follow, but from what I can gather there is some loose association between `Site.com` and `Community Builder`/`Community Administration` is there any documentation of this? And any explanation of why `Experience Builder Page` selection does not list *lightning builder pages*

Comment: Hi @Glen De Marco, I've opened a ticket with Salesforce as `Experience Builder` is now broken and returning an error when I attempt to open my community. I can't seem to "undo" removing the `login` "landing page" from `Site.com Studio` (though I did not publish this change it is still listed as an unpublished change with no undo button)

Comment: Sorry to hear. Hopefully, they can get that resolved ASAP. In the meanwhile, did you get a chance to see how to port a Community Builder Page to be one of the Home Page variations?

Comment: De Marco, I did get it resolved (I pushed a copy of the `siteDotCom` metadata binary to the org and it seemed to have reversed the missing `login` page in the `Site.com Studio`- I can set a `Home Page variation` but again - this does not affect where I am redirected after I reset a password.

Comment: I see, then that means your reset password page has some redirect logic that is preventing the Home Page from being the landing page once authenticated. You will need to see what the reset password page is doing in that case - it could be hardcoded and all these out of the box settings wouldn't matter at all.

Comment: see this screencast: https://www.screencast.com/t/2DpoMDat4JY

Comment: Thanks for the recording, that was very useful. The retUrl is then your main issue here. If there weren't a retUrl on the frontdoor redirect, you would hit the Home Page no problem. I'm unsure where the retUrl is being set for the frontdoor page, can you check the email template to verify how the link is being built? Maybe it is in the email template - that would be an easy fix.

Comment: the merge field in the email is `{!Community_Url}` that's it. This is influenced by `Site->Active Site Home Page` in some undocumented layering between "Community" and "Site"   I've simply created a *redirect* on that Visualforce page to the `Community URL` smh.

Comment: That was not the solution I was hoping for but easy enough. I still don't understand why the Site Active Home page is taking preference over the community home page. Maybe if you set the change password page in the Community Builder (granted, you need the Login pages activated by Salesforce to appear in the palette) the `{!Community_Url}` might change moving forward in the emails. I say this because it is the first time I see the Site Home Page override the community Home.